# How to reset sequence to match migration history

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I did some manual modifications to my database table, so now Prisma won't let me run `migrate dev`. I want to undo my changes, so I'm back in sync with what Prisma want me to have.

I had a lot of changes that I've managed to fix. But there's still one left that I don't know how to handle.

```
[*] Changed the `Product` table
  [*] Altered column `id` (sequence changed)
```

This is a Prostgres database. How do I reset the sequence to whatever value Prisma wants it to be? How do I know what value Prisma wants?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the `id` column had been re-created with an `INTEGER` type. The original table had a `SERIAL` type. After fixing that I could successfully run my migration.

The correct types to use was found in my very first `migration.sql` file in the `migrations` folder.

```
-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "Product" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "desc" TEXT,
    "longDesc" TEXT,
    "price" INTEGER,
    "imgUrl" TEXT,
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```